# Inserting a textbox value in Javascript doesn't pass ASP.NET validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 web form with inputs for a physical and mailing address. After entering a physical address, a user can tick a checkbox to fill in the mailing address if the information is the same.

This occurs via an OnClick function tied to the checkbox, which basically does this (I left out additional code):
`document.getElementById("<%= txtMailAddressStreetNumber.ClientID%>").value = document.getElementById("<%= txtPermAddressStreetNumber.ClientID%>").value;`

Each of the address textboxes has a `RequiredFieldValidator`. When I submit the form, it passes client-side validation and posts back to the server. There it fails (`Page.IsValid` is false). The textboxes that were populated by the OnClick function fail server-side validation unless I manually populate them.

I've tried calling `Page_ClientValidate('FormGroup');` (FormGroup is the name of the validation group) after assigning values, and doing this doesn't trigger any validation error messages for the textboxes. However, when I submit the form (postback), the values inserted via Javascript are all cleared and I have to manually enter them.

Code in the .aspx page:

```
<asp:Label CssClass="mainlabel" ID="lblPermAddressZipCode" runat="server" Text="Zip Code" AssociatedControlID="txtPermAddressZipCode" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtPermAddressZipCode" ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="FormGroup" CssClass="formerror" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPermAddressZipCode" Width="100" onclick="openDialog(1)" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="readOnlyTextBox" runat="server" />

<asp:CheckBox ID="cbPermIsMailAddress" onclick="UsePermanentAsMailingAddress()" runat="server" /><small>(same as above)</small>

<asp:Label CssClass="mainlabel" ID="lblMailAddressZipCode" runat="server" Text="Zip code" AssociatedControlID="txtMailAddressZipCode" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtMailAddressZipCode" ID="RequiredFieldValidator15" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="FormGroup" CssClass="formerror" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMailAddressZipCode" ReadOnly="true" onclick="openDialog(2)" CssClass="readOnlyTextBox" Width="100" runat="server" />
```

Javascript:

```
function UsePermanentAsMailingAddress() {
    //only copy if the address is complete

    if (document.getElementById("<%= permCityStateZipId.ClientID %>").value != '') {

        //exit if the box was unchecked
        if (!$("#<%= cbPermIsMailAddress.ClientID%>").is(':checked')) {
            return;
        }

        document.getElementById("<%= txtMailAddressZipCode.ClientID%>").value = document.getElementById("<%= txtPermAddressZipCode.ClientID%>").value;
        //the ID value is the answer
        document.getElementById("<%= mailCityStateZipId.ClientID%>").value = document.getElementById("<%= permCityStateZipId.ClientID %>").value;

        //Page_ClientValidate('FormGroup');
    }
    else {
        $("#<%= cbPermIsMailAddress.ClientID%>").removeAttr('checked');
        alert("Please enter a complete permanent address first.");
    }
}
```

Comment: we need to see your code.

Comment: @prospector I've added the code. I use a couple of hidden fields that contain a City-State-Zip ID. There is no validation performed on them client-side.

Comment: @prospector Also, it appears to pass validation client-side. Once it gets to the server, it fails. The page loads again, but without the values changed via JS (textboxes are empty). The page has `EnableViewState='true'`.

Comment: @prospector The issue is almost certainly to do with the `readonly` state of the textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `ReadOnly` property is set in the .aspx, any changes made to it client-side will be ignored when it's posted back. If you absolutely need to have the textboxes read-only, then remove the property from your .aspx and set it with JavaScript on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#<%= txtMailAddressZipCode.ClientID%>').prop('readonly', true);
});
```

This way the user won't be able to directly change the textbox (I assume you have some other way of filling the textbox), but any changes will be posted back rather than the original (empty) values.